# Is it possible to over ride the UIDeviceBatteryState variable?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm wondering if it's possible to override `var batteryState: UIDeviceBatteryState`. 
For example, if the `UIDeviceBatteryState` is set to `charging` (i.e. charger is plugged in) would it be possible to disable the charging by changing it to `unplugged`?

Thanks in advance!

(Apple docs on `UIDeviceBatteryState`):
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevicebatterystate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't override `batteryState`.  It is even marked as `{ get }` in the docs you linked.  The closest thing you'd be able to do is to hide the status bar completely within your app.

Answer (score 0):

var batteryState: UIDeviceBatteryState { get }

it is get only property so you can't set value